# codeigniter: form validation Not shown

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation

for some reason I made mistakes login form using codeigniter and hence my validation errors are not printed. What could be the problem?

The first charge controller errors should not occur, but when I click on the "Send" form when the fields are empty it does not display any error.

I'd love to help

Thanks in advance

the Controller:

```
   <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {


      public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
  }

  public function Index()
  {
    redirect(base_url() . 'user/login/');
  }

  public function login()
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      $data['title'] = 'Login';
      $data['page'] = 'user_register_login';
      $data['action'] = 'login';
      $this->load->view('includes/main',$data); 
    }
    else 
    {
      redirect(base_url());
    }

  }


        public function register()

    {

        $data ['action'] = 'register';
        $data ['page'] = 'user_register_login';
        $data ['title'] = 'הירשם למערכת';
        $this->load->view('includes/main', $data);


    }

            public function reset_password()

    {

        $data ['action'] = 'reset_password';
        $data ['page'] = 'user_register_login';
        $data ['title'] = 'איפוס סיסמה';
        $this->load->view('includes/main', $data);


    }





}
```

the view:

```
<h1>משתמשים</h1>


<ul>
              <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/user/login/">התחבר/התנתק</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/user/register/">הרשמה</a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/user/reset_password/">שכחתי סיסמה</a></li>

        </ul>

<?= validation_errors(); ?>
<?= form_open(base_url() . 'user/' . $action . '/'); ?>

<?php if($action == 'login'): ?>
  <label>Email: </label> <input type="text" name="email" size="20" /><br/>
  <label>Password: </label> <input type="password" name="password" size="20" /><br/> 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
<?php endif; ?>


<?php if ($action == 'register'): ?>

<h2> הירשם למערכת </h2>
<label>שם מלא: </label> <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
<label>כתובת מייל: </label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
<label>בחר סיסמה: </label> <input type="password" name="password" id="password"><br>
<label>חזור שוב על הסיסמה </label> <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2"><br>
<input type="submit" value="הירשם">

<?php endif; ?>


<?php if ($action == 'reset_password'): ?>

<h2> שכחתי סיסמה </h2>
<label>כתובת מייל: </label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
<input type="submit" value="אפס סיסמה">

<?php endif; ?>

</form>
```

Comment: You need to echo your validation errors. <? echo validation_errors(); ?>

Comment: <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?= form_open(base_url() . 'user/' . $action . '/'); ?>

Still not working

Comment: hmm..cough... can you just put the code <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> inside some container(<div class="errors"><?php echo validation_errors(); ?> </div) and inspect the section in the browser using F12 and let me know what appears there.

Comment: I did it. It seems it ignores the validation of rules and moves straight to Redirect

Comment: Please do test of validation errors inside controller itself              if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      echo validation_errors();
    }
    else 
    {
      echo "validation passed";
    }

Comment: Now it sends me to a blank white page. I can not understand what the error

Comment: Please post full directory structure of your project including controller+views+model and add view templates

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/httpdocs

Comment: Thanks for the code.. I am just checking it and will update you shortly

Comment: I appreciate your desire to help

Comment: remove the </form> in the last

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your issue dear.Please correct your code as mentioned below

Controller:user.php(change 2 functions)

```
 public function Index()
 {
  $data['title'] = 'Login';
  $data['page'] = 'user_register_login';
  $data['action'] = 'login';
  $this->load->view('includes/main',$data); 
}

 public function login()
 {
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
  if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
  {
   $this->index();
  }
  else 
 {
  redirect(base_url());
 }
```

}

View:add below line to file user_register_login.php

```
<div id="validationError" style="width:100%;float:left;height:25px;float:left">
 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
</div>
```

Most important check your base_url settings config/config.php $config['base_url'] for localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but for me it still does not work. I'm starting to think it's something to do with my server might ?? That make sense?